# Align Object to footage without knowing Camera data

Tags: rendering, objects, camera

I have a model, which represents a real world "machine". I now need to align the model in Blender to footage (taken with tripod, so it's static) from said machine. 
The models scale is accurate.

The problem is, i don't have access to the Cameras data (Focal Length, Sensor Width, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your footage contains horizontal and vertical features which are known to be parallel in the real-world 3D scene, then the [Blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) add-on will help you derive a matching camera location/perspective in Blender. You should then be able to make simple bounding-boxes in scene, and align your model to the bounding boxes.